# How to create new object using data from icalendar file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called event which attributes are:

```
     string "name"
     string "location"
     string "lecturer"
     date "start_time"
     date "end_time"`
```

I want to take data from icalendar type file and create event instances. How should I do this ? I tried to do a method in `events_controller.rb`:

```
      def new_method

      @ievent_file = File.open("calendar2.ics")
      @ievents = Icalendar::Event.parse(@ievent_file)
      @ievent = @ievents.first
      @ievent = Event.new(name:@ievent.summary,location:@ievent.location, lecturer:@ievent.description, start_time:@ievent.dtstart, end_time:@ievent.dtend)

      end
```

But then what I should do with it ? Should I call this function in view or maybe should I take this code to method called `create` which looks like this:

```
def create

@event = Event.new(event_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @event.save
    format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my understanding calendar2.ics have many records, if you want to loop through all the event inside calendar2.ics and save it to your event table (import ics file to event table)

below are sample steps, inside your routes file create one method

```
resources :events do
  collection {
    get  :transfer_data_from_ics
  }
end
```

inside your events_controller you create 2 methods

```
def transfer_data_from_ics
  # get data from ics
    @ievent_file = File.open("calendar2.ics")
    @ievents = Icalendar::Event.parse(@ievent_file)      
  # loop through
    @ievents.each do |i_event|
      Event.create(
        name: i_event.summary,
        location: i_event.location, 
        lecturer: i_event.description, 
        start_time: i_event.dtstart, 
        end_time: i_event.dtend)
    end
  # route back to events list
    redirect_to events_path
end
```

to get the method called you can create menu / button with link_to as follow:

```
<%= link_to "Transfer data", transfer_data_from_ics_events_path %>
```

Comment: I did what You wrote here, so now should I call this method somewhere ? Because when i enter localhost:3000/events i don't see any events. (/events is my route for showing all events using method called index) –

Comment: Okey I saved all the data entering localhost:3000/events/transfer_data_from_ics. Just curious, could I do this another way, or should I always enter ./....... to get the method done ?

Comment: yes, you can check  my answer above I just added on bottom